What is the difference between the part_type value wide and compact in clickhouse?
I want to know the difference between the part_type(a column in system.parts) value wide and compact in clickhouse and the meaning of parameter min_bytes_for_wide_part.
I want to know the difference between the part_type(a column in system.parts) value wide and compact in clickhouse and the meaning of parameter `min_bytes_for_wide_part`.

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree#mergetree-data-storage
Data parts can be stored in Wide or Compact format. In Wide format each column is stored in a separate file in a filesystem, in Compact format all columns are stored in one file. Compact format can be used to increase performance of small and frequent inserts.
Data storing format is controlled by the min_bytes_for_wide_part and min_rows_for_wide_part settings of the table engine. If the number of bytes or rows in a data part is less then the corresponding setting's value, the part is stored in Compact format. Otherwise it is stored in Wide format. If none of these settings is set, data parts are stored in Wide format.

Whether there is a parameter that controls the part size to reach a certain minimum value before the merge is performed

There is no such parameter. MergeSelector uses a sophisticated algorithm and its goal to minimize number of merges the same time keeping the reasonable number of parts.

Now, I have a kafka engine table that consumes data from a topic in kafka, how to optimize the consumption rate when there is only one topic partition, now kafka is piling up a lot of data, any optimization suggestions
